# i want show notification on stock value change in android

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, stock

I developed stock market app.now I want to develop app that have features like notification when stock value has been change to 1 % of current ...help me ...thanks in advance..i want show notification on stock value change in android

Comment: What you tired till.

Comment: hey...develop whole app about stock market..but confuse to develop feature like that.

Comment: Have you googled for "notification in android".

Comment: ya....i know about notification...but i want develope service that check continue fro stock value

Answer (score 1):

Try the following it may helps you

1) First take one service in your application

2) In the service check the stock market updates frequently

**EDIT**

```
public class StockService extends Service{

Thread t=new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            checkStockUpdates();
            Thread.sleep(give how much time you want);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    t.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void checkStockUpdates(){
    //write code here for checking stock market updates
    //if any updates found send notification here itself
}

}
```

3) If you observe any change then you can send notification to user

Following is the code for send notification

```
manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* Invoking the default notification service */
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");

        manager.notify(1234, mBuilder.build());
```

**Note : Thread is lightweight so if you write while loop also it doesn't effect on Application performance.**

hope it will helps you.

Comment: thanks for replay...i know about notification...but haw build service like that..help me

Comment: but how to start that service and stay continue even after application closed

Comment: @Ajay Patel start the service in MainActivity, after starting the service it will run in background even if you close the application also.